# I have accidently archived an important mail. I searched in "All Mails" with the enough data, but it was not their either. How can I find it now?

Tags: gmail

I know everything about mail such as who sent it, what was it about etc. but it was not in "**all mails**". I even searched in the search icon with enough data, but still, I could not find it.

Comment: Did  it have any other label attached to it?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no other labels attached to the message you have a few options.

- Find any email from that person, open that email, click the three vertical dots, and select "filter messages like this". You should now see all messages from that person.
- if you have a lot of emails from that person you can add to the filter to include a key word, or a date range.